# Using iOS Static Libraries without adding .a Files

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-libraries

We can use [iOS Static Libraries without adding header files into the project](http://muthukumarela.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/ios-static-libraries-without-adding-header-files/).
But i want to use the Static Libraries without adding .a files into the project

Comment: What do you mean? .a file IS the library... Unless you have source code - in that case you can add source to the project. The link you provided is very useful - thanks. But it doesn't mean you're using library without header files - linker searches for headers in the folders that you specify.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But We dont have to add header files manually. I am expecting the same for .a files

Comment: Xcode must "see" the .a file being referenced to, otherwise, it cannot link, as rokjarc has said.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative way of referencing .a files rather than adding them into the project, similar to  what is been done for the header files in my blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution 

 Path of the static library should be added in  ->target->build settings-> Other Linker Flags 
eg.)

/Source/iPhoneApp/libs/Connection/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libConnection.a /Source/iPhoneApp/libs/SocialNetwork/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSocialNetwork.a

Answer (score 0):

If you built the library, you can use dependencies to add the library project to your app project without the hassle of configuring stuff.

To do so, just drag the .xcodeproj file from your library to the app project, go to the app target properties, and add a dependency on that library, just as you'd add a public framework such as MapKit.